# Compile Time Signed Shift Operator

Tags: c++, c++98

This is a macro, and thus I hate it, but it "Works" for what I want:

```
#define signed_shift(val,shift) ((shift) < 0 ? (val) >> -(shift) : (val) << (shift))
```

It needs to be compile time (constexpr would work in C++11, but I'm stuck in c++98).

Anyone have a better way (boost is ok).

Comment: I, for one, would add parentheses: `((shift) < 0 ? (val) >> -(shift) : (val) << (shift))`

Comment: Does it really have to be compile time by standard definition?
I suspect that with compiler optimizations on it probably already is compile time in practice. Is that not be good enough?

Comment: @PeterSW Want it for template arguments, so unfortunately not.

Comment: @rodrigo you are completely right, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <int val, int shift>
struct signed_shift
{
    static const int result = (shift < 0) ? (val >> -shift) : (val << shift);
};

int main()
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(signed_shift<4, 3>::result == 32);
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(signed_shift<4, 0>::result == 4);
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(signed_shift<4, -1>::result == 2);
}
```

Comment: hahaha i'm dumb. That's totally right. Should switch the static const int to enum {result} though.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Why an enum? The result of shifting an int is an int.

Comment: @molbdnilo enforces const expression on assign, enforces that you can't take the address of it, ect. Mostly, its a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with templates (the static member is out-of-class since C++03 does not support in-class initialization of static members):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, T val, T shift>
struct signed_shift {
    static T const value;
};

template<typename T, T val, T shift>
T const signed_shift<T,val,shift>::value
    = ((shift) < 0 ? val >> -shift : val << shift);

int main()
{
    std::cout << signed_shift<int, 1, 3>::value << '\n';
}
```